# "New Spring Starter Project" wizard in STS 3.8.4 shows "IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://start.spring.io"

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-boot, proxy

I am trying to start a new Spring project. But when I open the "New Spring Starter Project" wizard, it shows "IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://start.spring.io"
I am using STS 3.8.4 and my firewall is already deactivated. Please let me know how I can solve the problem.
[image]

Comment: This looks like a network issue or a firewall issue as I can access the URL in a browser. Are you able to access this through a browser? If yes, then download the ZIP and open it in STS

Answer (score 0):

```
I rebooted my smartphone, the internet device. then opened the command prompt   on laptop and executed the following commands:-
```

1. ipconfig/release (it released the current IP Configuration)
2. ipconfig/renew   (DHCP server assigned a new IP address)

   The above solved the problem.